# Why my bluetooth is not detected by my linux and how to install its driver?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I have installed Linux Debian 11.5 on my HP X360 Spectre. when I check Bluetooth I found it always grayed and a message: `No Bluetooth found. plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth"`.

If I do this in a terminal:

```bash
sudo lsmod | grep blue
```

I get nothing (empty output). But after some messing up with commands that I found on the internet like bootctl, bluetoothctl, lspci... I get this:

```bash
sudo lsmod | grep blue
#Output:
 bluetooth             753664  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
 ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
 libaes                 16384  2 bluetooth,aesni_intel
 rfkill                 32768  9 hp_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
 crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

So what is my Bluetooth driver? and how to install it?

On Windows 10, 11,.. the Bluetooth works without any problem but on Linux system like Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora.. they have same issue.

```bash
sudo rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

`rfkill` doesn't show Bluetooth!.

```bash
sudo lspci | grep blue
#empty output
```

```bash
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
```

```bash
sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

```bash
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service

    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-11-14 19:15:21 CET; 21min ago Docs: man:bluetoothd(8) Main PID: 3977 (bluetoothd) Status: "Running" Tasks: 1 (limit: 18814) Memory: 1.3M CPU: 46ms CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service └─3977 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

    Nov 14 19:15:21 debian systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
    Nov 14 19:15:21 debian bluetoothd[3977]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
    Nov 14 19:15:21 debian systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
    Nov 14 19:15:21 debian bluetoothd[3977]: Starting SDP server
    Nov 14 19:15:21 debian bluetoothd[3977]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
```

```bash
sudo lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
bluetooth             753664  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbcore               331776  5 xhci_hcd,usbhid,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
```

```bash
sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[sudo] password for raindrop7:
  [    1.501334] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
  [    1.501920] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
  [    5.758516] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
  [    5.875550] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
  [    5.875793] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
  [    5.890039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode
  [    5.890356] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
  [    5.890380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
  [    5.890424] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
  [    6.270240] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof/sof-cml.ri
  [    6.270246] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
  [    6.270247] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:17:0
  [    6.361112] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:7:0-47d07
  [    6.361113] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:18:1 Kernel ABI 3:17:0
  [    6.586224] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
  [    6.586255] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  [    6.586259] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  [    6.586261] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  [    6.586269] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  [    6.773627] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-hda-generic-2ch.tplg
  [    8.685217] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  [    8.685219] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  [    8.685222] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

So I've written down these outputs so that an expert can make sense of them and tell me what to do and which driver should I install.